# How to set up OneDrive API for game updating

Tags: c#, winforms, onedrive

So, I wanted to write a game launcher app that also updates it. Since I only have access to OneDrive, I want to push the updates from my personal cloud to the user. It goes like this:

1. The launcher checks if there are any new files to download.
2. If there are new files, it downloads them, If not, the user can play the game.
3. After downloading, the app replaces the old ones.
4. If a file was removed from the cloud version (e.g. a backgroung sound) it should delete it from the desktop version.

Comment: It seems that you'll create an alternate OneDrive sync client ;P

Comment: The problem is with your question is that you listed things that you want in your application, but you haven't showed any code or effort that you made. A simply google search tells you how to use OneDrive API from .NET  ([example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631823.aspx))